# Playscape Publishing Kit. Unity 4.6.6. Unable to build on a Mac

Tags: playscape

Unable to build the project with Playscape Publishing Kit v1.11 on a Mac

here is the log file
https://yadi.sk/i/VJ9DdRpMi2VVb

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It seems that your app contains reference to more than 64K methods. We've documented a page in our wiki to help you resolve this:
[Solving Error - Too many method references](https://github.com/Playscape/Documentation/wiki/Solving-Error---Too-many-method-references---max-is-65536)